$GITLAB_ENV used to pass variables to other sections of the job in gitlab-ci is empty/undefined
Gitlab CI docs suggest pass variables from script to other sections using a variable named $GITLAB_ENV https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-from-the-script-section-to-another-section-in-the-same-job
Running pipeline throws error with echo "<content>" >> $GITLAB_ENV, says ambiguous redirect and dies. This variable does not have value in runtime. Looking for $GITLAB_ENV only is mentioned in this documentation, does not appear on Gitlab variables.
I have looked for more examples to define variables as documentations say, but there is no more resources.
There is a way to make this work, I need to use a variable value generated in script section, value for a filename to be included in artifacts:
my-job:
  script:
  - MAIN_DIR=$[[ inputs.root-name ]]-api
  - echo "MAIN_DIR=$MAIN_DIR" >> $GITLAB_ENV

  artifacts:
    paths:
    - $MAIN_DIR/file.txt


I have a gitlab job that looks something like this:
Example:
  stage: example
  script: 
    - touch job.env
    - echo "MAIN_DIR=${MAIN_DIR}" > job.env
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - job.env
    reports:
      dotenv: job.env


I believe the standard way of passing environment variables to other stages as artifacts is by using dotenv.
If you just want your variable to be accessible in the same job, I would just use a global variable/job variable like:
#option 1
variables:
    MAIN_DIR: "value"

Example:
  #option 2
  variables:
    MAIN_DIR: "other value"
  stage: example
  script: 
    - echo "$MAIN_DIR"

This post also answers something similar and might be closer to what you want: set up global variables dynamically in gitlab-ci

Pass value to other stages/jobs works fine, and is like you show; what I mean is a variable created in script used in the same job but in the part artifacts.

@Bernardo Gomez Is there a reason you can't just create the variable as a job variable? i.e. create a variables section in your job?
